# Recommended reading reordering

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

My one problem with Recommended readings is that if I add a new book it gets a added at the very bottom. I would prefer for it to be up top, or, even better, I would prefer to be able to re-arrange the books in such a way that I can display them in order of 'importance' or using some sort of categories.

Is this kind of featured plan ? It seems like re-ordering would be trivial to implement considering it could currently be "faked" by a client-side script that just switches the fields between two books.